# How to remove ONLY the last li from a ul (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a list in which to add elements to it and only to remove one by one when "Remove" button is pressed. Unfortunately, something weird happens and if I add 2 elements the remove button deletes them both.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".additem").on("click", function(){
    var val = $("input").val();
    if(val!=="") {
      var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val);
      $(".list-item").append(elem);
      $("input").val("");
      $(".removeitem").on("click", function() {
        $(".list-item li:last-child").remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You are nesting click events. Each time you click on `.additem`, you are adding a new `.removeitem` click event. Just don't nest these events

Comment: Please add some example code that's runnable. That way it's easier to show you working code.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I feel dumb now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your program that each time you add element to your list there is a click event listener is added to your remove button

I will explain more deeply how your code work so you will understand the problem:

Firstly this is our page that we will work on it as example:

[image]

Also our javascript code:

```
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".additem").on("click", function(){
    var val = $("input").val();
    if(val!=="") {
      var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val);
      $(".list-item").append(elem);
      $("input").val("");
      $(".removeitem").on("click", function() {
        i++;
        console.log("Call Remove Event " + i);
        $(".list-item li:last-child").remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**First call**: when you add `item10` to your list, remove click event listener will be added 1 time to your remove button and when you click remove `item10` will only remove from list

also console output : `Call Remove Event 1`

**Second call**: when you add also `item10` to your list, remove click event listener will be added 2 times to remove button and when you click remove `item10` and `item9` will be removed from list

console output:

```
Call Remove Event 2
Call Remove Event 3
```

[image]

The reason for that is when you clicked remove button the last element of your list will be removed 2 times directly it's like you are clicking remove button two times.

**Third call**: when you add `item9` to your list, remove click event listener will be added 3 times to remove button and when you click remove `item9`,`item8` and `item7` will be removed from list

console output:

```
Call Remove Event 4
Call Remove Event 5
Call Remove Event 6
```

[image]

To solve this problem you can either try this way using [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".additem").on("click", function(){
    var val = $("input").val();
    if(val!=="") {
      var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val);
      $(".list-item").append(elem);
      $("input").val("");
      $(".removeitem").on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(".list-item li:last-child").remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This method will keep any additional handlers on `removeitem` element from being executed.

Or simply you can put `removeitem` on click function outside scope of `additem` on click function and it will work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".additem").on("click", function(){
    var val = $("input").val();
    if(val!=="") {
      var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val);
      $(".list-item").append(elem);
      $("input").val("");     
    }
  });
  $(".removeitem").on("click", function() {
        $(".list-item li:last-child").remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated ! Very explicit :)

Comment: your welcome!

if the answer solved your problem mark it as accepted to be a reference in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding a click handler to all elements with the `removeitem` class for every element with the `additem` class. This will cause several events doing the same thing. Take the on click function out of the other on click function as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".additem").on("click", function() {
    var val = $("input").val();
    if (val !== "") {
      var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val);
      $(".list-item").append(elem);
      $("input").val("");
    }
  });
  $(".removeitem").on("click", function() {
    $(".list-item li:last-child").remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put delete listener out side the add listener .

```js
$(".additem").on("click", function() {
  var val = $("input").val();
  if (val !== "") {
    var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val);
    $(".list-item").append(elem);
   // $("input").val("");
  }
});
$(".removeitem").on("click", function() {
  $(".list-item li:last-child").remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type- 'text'/>
<input type='button' class='additem' value='Add' />
<input type='button' class='removeitem' value='Remove' />
<ul class='list-item'>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! All is light now :)

Comment: If answer address your problem please up vote and accept ans. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

first get length of ul element and then remove last li element by index has below,

$("#btnid").click(function(){
        var val = $('ul li').length;
        $("ul li").eq(val-1).remove();
 });